# How to get and set values from a UPS device using SNMP?

Tags: java, snmp4j

I have a java web application running in my workplace. 
I was asked to create a new application to "communicate" with network devices and read their statuses. 
As an example I started working with a UPS, which is connected to my network with its own Network Interface Card. 
I can monitor its status and details with its built-on platform entering with its IP address on a browser. But the idea is to add some of these details to the original web application.

To my understanding I can use a SNMP library for Java and create an application to get and set values to it. In my case i'm using the SNMP4j(V3) library, I imported it to Eclipse (IDE), but have no idea on how to continue from there really.

Comment: I'd start by looking for articles, blogs and documentation on the SNMP protocol, how you connect, get information, etc. From there, I'd research on accessing UPS devices via SNMP and see if there is anything particular to the type of UPS you're using or if everything can be done via basic options. Then I'd go through the documentation of the Java library.

Comment: I have searched a lot of documentation, I know there are some unique codes for accessing devices with SNMP protocol, using the OIDs of each device, but how can I translate those codes into Java language? Also I'm not really sure how to read the SNMP documentation, it's my first time using an external library on Java. (plus have little to no experience at all with Java )